# Show an element on hover and hide back when hover ends

Tags: jquery

I want to show #hover when #original is hovered, with a fadeIn. And #hover should fadeOut back when the user stops hovering over #original.

I'm using this code. Using this, the element is shown on hover, but it doesn't fadeOut back when hover ends.

```
$('#hover').hide();

$("#original").hover(function () {
$('#hover').fadeIn('');
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Do you have a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your HTML?  Most likely this can be done with CSS alone and no code at all.

Comment: `#hover{opacity:0 transition: 600ms linear}` `#original:hover ~ #hover{opacity:1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.hover` has two callback.

**Syntax**

```
.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) );
```

> **Description:** Bind two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.

```
$("#original").hover(function () {
  $('#hover').fadeIn();
},function () {
  $('#hover').fadeOut();
});
```

#### [**`Official Document`**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)